Añadir Array a un objeto PHP MVC
Necesito ayuda con el proceso de añadir un producto al Carrito mediante un modelo MVC en PHP. Estoy aprendiendo el modelo vista controlador y me he quedado atascado con un error de concepto al no tener claro 100% el flujo. Básicamente el error que tengo es que añadir el producto al carrito, no se me añade al array productos, simplemente me lo sustituye y además la $quantity solo se acumula una vez. Pienso que el error está en los constructores o el orden de comunicación.
Realizo un fetch a la funcion addCart() del CartProductController
async function anadirAlCarrito(id)
{
    let response = await fetch('http://localhost/mvc-country-app/Public/cartproduct/addCart', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ id }),
    });
    let responseData = await response.json();
    console.log(responseData);

    if(responseData)// Aqui he de controlar el estado del
    {
        const carrito = document.getElementById('tbody_cart');

            carrito.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<tr id="item_${responseData.id}">
                <td>${responseData.id}</td>
                <td>${responseData.nombre}</td>
                <td>${responseData.stock}</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>`)
    }
}


<?php
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/../Models/CartProduct.php');
    
    class CartProductController extends Controller {
    
        public $cartProductModel;
    
        public function __construct(PDO $coneccion)
        {   
            if($this->cartProductModel)
            {
                $this->cartProductModel;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->cartProductModel = new CartProduct($coneccion);
            }
        }
    
        public function home()
        {
            var_dump($this->cartProductModel);
        }
    
        public function addCart()
        {
            $res = new Result();
            $postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $body = json_decode($postData, true);
            $id = $body['id'];
    
            $this->cartProductModel->addProductCart($id, $this->cartProductModel);
           
            $json = json_encode($this->cartProductModel, true);
            echo $json;
            $res->result = json_encode($json);
           
            $res->success = true;
            $res->message = 'El registro fue eliminado correctamente';
    
        }
    
    }

En esta trato de crear un nuevo objeto Resul para manejar la petición, y obtengo el ID del producto. Después trato de comunicarme con el Modelo CartProduct, pasandole el $cartProductModel y que obtiene correctamente el producto de la base de datos y devuelve el carrito:
<?php
    class CartProduct extends Orm{

        public $productos = [];
        public $quantity;
        public $sub_total;

        public function __construct(PDO $coneccion)
        {
            parent::__construct('id','productos', $coneccion);
            $this->productos = [];
            $this->quantity = 0;
            $this->sub_total = 0;
        }


        public function addProductCart($id, $cart)
        {
            $producto = $this->getById($id);
            $cart->productos[] = $producto;
            $cart->quantity++;            
            return $cart;
        }
        
        public function getQuantity()
        {
            return $this->quantity;
        }
    }

El problema esta en el servidor, en PHP, al añadir un nuevo producto al carrito. Concretamente en la funcion addProductCart() del CartProduct(Modelo) al devolver el carrito con los productos acumulados. Estoy incrementando cada vez que se añade un producto el quantity, pero como veo solo se incrementa una vez, es decir, resetea el carrito en cada llamada. La respuesta que recibo en el cliente cada vez que añado un producto es esta:
productos:{"productos":[{"id":"3","nombre":"Alcachofas","precio":"0.00","descripcion":null,"categoria":"Verdura","estacion":null,"stock":"12","imagen":null,"huerto_id":null}],"quantity":1,"sub_total":0}

No está claro si el problema es en el cliente (Javascript) o en el servidor (PHP), por favor, aclara ese punto. Por otra parte, explica si el fetch ocurre varias veces y si es así explica de qué modo haces persistir los datos del carrito en el servidor. Nada de eso aparece explicado en la pregunta ni en el código que compartes.

Gracias por tu ayuda, he editado la pregunta dando más información. Realizo simplemente un fetch que llama a la funcion CartProductController::addCart() , en esta se llama a CartProduct::addProductCart(id, cart) y aquí es donde extraigo el producto segun el ID de la base de datos e intento añadirlo al carrito $cart->productos[] = $producto; que le paso por variable

Ya, pero, ¿en un solo fetch le mandas varios productos al servidor para ser agregados? ¿de qué forma los mandas? Yo no veo en ningún lado que estés enviando varios productos. Y, si eso ocurre en diferentes fetch, dinos de qué modo haces que los productos de los fetch anteriores persistan del lado del servidor.

Se hace un fetch cada vez que pulso el boton y le paso el ID, para extraer el producto a través de Orm::getById(Id) de la base de datos. QUizás sea que no hago bien que persistan los datos en un objeto CartProduct en el servidor. ¿O sería más conveniente hacer persistir ese cart product en el lado de cliente?

Pues ahí está el problema. Por cada fetch el proceso empieza nuevamente. Debes persistir, sea del lado del servidor con una variable de sesión o de otro modo, sea en el cliente. O, cambiando la lógica,  por ejemplo escoger todos los productos y hacer un solo fetch con todos los productos que se deseen comprar. Aún en ese caso conviene alguna persistencia, por si el usuario quiere modificar algo del carrito.

He depurado el flujo de ejecución haciendo uso de las Sesiones y he conseguido persistir los datos en el servidor y mandarlos correctamente. ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!
